# django production environment is using the wrong db

Tags: django, deployment, digital-ocean

I am writing my first 'self-made deployment'. Writing the deploy script using fabric. I have added an export to .bashrc on my production machine to export a key:value {'DIGITAL_OCEAN': True} so I can add some conditions in my settings to use databases based on local or production environments.

```
SETTINGS.PY

import os
if 'DIGITAL_OCEAN' in os.environ:
        ON_DO = True
else:
        ON_DO = False

if ON_DO:
        DATABASES = {
        'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
                'NAME': 'user',
                'USER': 'user',
                'PASSWORD': 'pass',
                'HOST': 'localhost',
                'PORT': '',
                }
        }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'localuser',
            'USER': 'localuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'localpass',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
            }
```

NOW... If I run an ssh command like '$ python manage.py migrate' all goes well ON_DO is discovered and it goes well, but in my deploy script, listed below, ON_DO comes through as false, I had this happen spontaneously before and then it corrected itself (maybe with a gunicorn or nginx restart) so I tried adding some restarts to the script, but no luck so far and I am out of ideas.

```
def server():

        '''IDK'''
        env.host_string = 'ip.ip.ip.ip'
        env.user = 'root'

def pull_deploy():

        '''Makes the server pull it from git repo at bitbucket'''

        path = '/home/django/'


        print(red('BEGINNING PULL DEPLOY'))

        with cd('%s' % path) :
                run('pwd')
                print(green('Pulling Master from Bitbucket'))
                run('git pull origin master')

                print(green('SKIPPING installing requirements'))
                run('source %spyenv/bin/activate && pip install -r langalang/requirements.txt' % path)

                print('Collecting static files')
                run('source %spyenv/bin/activate && python langalang/manage.py collectstatic' % path)

                print('Restarting Gunicorn')
                run('sudo service gunicorn restart')
                print('Restarting Nginx')
                run('nginx -s reload')

                print('Making migrations')
                run('source %spyenv/bin/activate && python langalang/manage.py makemigrations' % path)

                print('Migrating DB')
                run('source %spyenv/bin/activate && python langalang/manage.py migrate' % path)

                print('Restarting Gunicorn')
                run('sudo service gunicorn restart')
                print('Restarting Nginx')
                run('nginx -s reload')
                print(red('DONE'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had declared my environment variable 'ON_DO' in ~.bashrc or ~.profile and those only export the variable from a login shell. I guess django doesn't count as a login shell when it runs by itself. I had to export them from the .wsgi file in django itself.

That file only runs in production as far as I can tell so it only outputs the variables to the production system.

Answer (score -1):

@deltaskelta Why would you set the variable in `wsgi.py` file? Doesn't it defeat the purpose as this variable will also be set in your development environment.

Here is the shell script that I wrote.

```
#!/bin/sh

ps aux | grep usr/bin/[p]ython

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    export UNIQUE_KEY='value'
    python ~/project_name/manage.py runserver 0:8000
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

What this does is, sets the `UNIQUE_KEY` environment variable whenever it executes and unsets it as soon as it stops. **Moreover, it works with `crontab` as well.** This works because shell scripts executed via crontab are run in a `non-interactive non-login shell session`.

Probably an in-depth understanding of distinct shell sessions would help.

> The Difference between **Login, Non-Login, Interactive**, and **Non-Interactive Shell** Sessions
>
> The bash shell reads different configuration files depending on how the session is started.
>
> One distinction between different sessions is whether the shell is being spawned as a **"login"** or **"non-login"** session.
>
> A login shell is a shell session that begins by authenticating the user. If you are signing into a terminal session or through SSH and authenticate, your shell session will be set as a **"login"** shell.
>
> If you start a new shell session from within your authenticated session, like we did by calling the bash command from the terminal, a **non-login** shell session is started. You were were not asked for your authentication details when you started your child shell.
>
> Another distinction that can be made is whether a shell session is **interactive, or non-interactive**.
>
> An **interactive** shell session is a shell session that is attached to a terminal. A **non-interactive** shell session is one is not attached to a terminal session.

[Check this link for details - Digital Ocean Tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps)